# Bootstrap Carousel other content than image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to use the twitter bootstrap carousel in a personal project.
So far it works really well because I use the example of the bootstrap homepage.

Now I want to place simple html content instead of images there.
This content should then rotate same way as the pictures.
The text I put in is shown in the carousel-caption and text I put in the carousel caption is not being displayed.

Example:

```
    <div class="item">
        This is the text or html code i want to place
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Carousel caption text<p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to get this work?
Perhaps theres is a way to declare a white span with say 300 x 300 px where i can place some content.

You should know that I at a beginner level. I am now learning html, css, js, mongodb, bootstrap, node.js. But this is a little to much for me now.

many thanks
Daniel

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    div.new_html_code {
      width:150px;
      height:100px;
      min-width:150px;
      min-height:100px;
      max-width:200px;
      max-height:100px;
      overflow:hidden;
      display:block;
      border:1px solid red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<!--
some html stuff here, I am just giving the basic layout
-->
    <div class="item">
        <div class="new_html_code"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
            <p>Carousel caption text<p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

If you have replaced html/css from carousel and are not able to correct it, get back the original stuff.
Then slowly start replacing with your code, and be very careful with the following css-attributes, they not only help to find errors (like the most useful css borders), but they also help to stop new content that is added, from bloating previous one (max width/height css attributes).

Pay close attention to the following css-attributes:

```
      min-width:150px;
      min-height:100px;
      max-width:200px;
      max-height:100px;
      overflow:hidden;
      border:1px solid red;
```

Do not modify the z-indexes and opacity first work with the ones I have given above and then start doing complex stuff, ask again if you have some doubt and sorry for typos I have less time.

Comment: Hello Nina, this is great!:-) Exactly what i was looking for. It works. I will modify it a little. But now I think I understand how to place my own elements in this site although using bootstrap. But that's css:-) Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

The `carousel-caption` class is bad for you. Don't use it if you don't want to show pictures and you're fine. It's even semantically wrong to define your html content as a *caption*. Just leave the class away and use a plain `div`

```
<div>
    <h4>Thumbnail label</h4>
    <p>Carousel caption text<p>
</div>
```

Also these smooth shadows will disappear then. And thats good, since we don't want them on pure text (although they may look nice on pictures).

Answer (score 10):

You didn't close the `carousel-caption` div. Probably is your problem. If you look at the documentation of bootstrap carousel, there is no different between using images or text inside each item.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
   <!-- Carousel items -->
   <div class="carousel-inner">
     <div class="active item"><p>1</p></div>
     <div class="item"><p>2</p></div>
     <div class="item"><p>3</p></div>
   </div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Look at the behaviour of this code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QYFa2/

Comment: I'm sorry!
I lost the closing tag by copying the text into the question.
My source code is valid.
Ok, I deleted the carousel-caption as you said and now I can see the text I typed in.
The problem is that the whole site is loosing it's "form". Following elements will not stay on their place and destroy the layout.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Thank you

Comment: Perhaps I can give it a hight and a boarder or something.

Answer (score 10):

@GLES there is a very simple method to use carousel without any image. Actually the position property of *.carousel-caption* was causing the problem. Simply set it to *static*

```
.carousel-caption { position:static; }
```

Here is the demo for that

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/esy38/)

Answer (score 2):

Rondell may be a jQuery plugin for displaying galleries and different content the approach you wish.

[View Demo](http://projects.sebastianhelzle.net/jquery.rondell/) i have use this plugin its quite easy to use ,download [Source Code](http://projects.sebastianhelzle.net/jquery.rondell/)

Comment: Looks like you were in hurry, forgot to post full link!

Answer (score 2):

Just **delete carousel-caption** class and everything will be great