# Bootstrap Carousel - Full width, fixed height images with contained controls?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm working on a new website based on Bootstrap and am using the default Bootstrap carousel. I've got it running perfectly, but was hoping to modify the image slides to be full width yet retain a fixed height (cropping if necessary).

At the same time, I want to keep the controls (left/right & dot indicators) and the captions inside a container so that it lines up with the body content. I've tried simply putting the control code into a `<div class="container"></div>` as well as a row and span div. However, nothing will work. Alternatively, I can do the opposite by containing the images while making the controls full width.

Is there a quick and easy way of doing this? Here is the block of code for my carousel:

```
<div id="home-carousel" class="carousel slide">
<!-- Carousel items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
        <img src="img/carousel-1.jpg">
        <a href="#"><div class="carousel-caption">
            <p class="carousel-title">This is the caption.</p>
            <p class="hidden-phone">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mauris ligula, ultrices accumsan imperdiet eu, convallis in nunc. Nam commodo augue a libero vestibulum sed convallis enim mattis.</p>
        </div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/carousel-2.jpg">
        <a href="#"><div class="carousel-caption">
            <p class="carousel-title">I'm a caption, too!</p>
            <p class="hidden-phone">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, c</p>
        </div></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="img/carousel-3.jpg">
        <a href="#"><div class="carousel-caption">
            <p class="carousel-title">Yeah, me too.</p>
            <p class="hidden-phone">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin mauris ligula, ultrices accumsan imperdiet eu, convallis in nunc. Nam commodo augue a libero vestibulum sed convallis enim mattis.</p>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Carousel nav -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#home-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>
<a class="carousel-control" href="#home-carousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left"></i></a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#home-carousel" data-slide="next"><i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></a>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11914716/bootstrap-carousel-other-content-than-image/11915379#11915379

Comment: did you manage to resolved this issue? I am also trying to make a bootstrap carousel with similar effect.